# Manually setting date in Bootstrap datepicker sets one month more

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

When I am manually setting date in datepicker of bootstrap , It is setting date but by itself it is increasing month by one,  For example if I am setting date 21/10/2015 then my textbox shows right value whereas datepicker calender shows 21 nov 2015.    My code is as follows: `

```
    <div id='datepickerSimple' class='datepicker-input input-group controls'>
   <input id='textdate' class='form-control' placeholder='dd/MM/yyyy' data-rule-           required='true' data-format='DD/MM/YYYY' type='text' />
   <span class='input-group-addon'>
       <span class='icon-calendar' data-time-icon='icon-time' id="datecal" data-date-icon='icon-calendar'></span>
   </span>
</div>`
```

and my jquery is as follows                                                     `$('#datecal').val("21/10/2015");`                                                        plse guide me how to set right date in calender and what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Why not use `update`? http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/release/methods.html#update

Comment: i have already tried but no other methods of setting date worked for me.

Comment: Please help masterminds,  am in trouble because of this.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old question, but for those who stuck to this problem Bootstrap Datepicker accepts month input from 0 to 11.

So January is represented as 0 and December as 11

If you want month as October please set date as below

```
$('#textdate').datepicker('setDate', new Date(2015, 09, 21)); 
$('#textdate').datepicker('update');
$('#textdate').val('');
```